# WebHDFS OPEN command returns empty results

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, webhdfs

I created a simple file in HDFS at the path /user/admin/foo.txt

I can see the contents of this file in Hue.

How I issue the command

```
curl -i http://namenode:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/admin/foo.txt?op=OPEN
```

I get the response

```
HTTP/1.1 307 TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Tue, 24 Nov 2015 16:20:15 GMT
Date: Tue, 24 Nov 2015 16:20:15 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Tue, 24 Nov 2015 16:20:15 GMT
Date: Tue, 24 Nov 2015 16:20:15 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Location: http://datanode:50075/webhdfs/v1/user/admin/foo.txt?op=OPEN&namenoderpcaddress=nameservice1&offset=0
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(6.1.26.cloudera.4)
```

why is the content-length: 0?? I was hoping that this would list the contents of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Execute:

```
curl -i http://datanode:50075/webhdfs/v1/user/admin/foo.txt?op=OPEN&namenoderpcaddress=nameservice1&offset=0
```

As for the explanation - when using WebHDFS to open a file you have to do the following:

1. You don't know which node the file resides on, so you ask the namenode.
2. The namenode returns you a datanode containing the file.
3. You can then open the file itself by talking directly to the datanode.

So this activity is expected. See https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html for more information.